# How to adjust uiscrollview after adding view (autolayout)

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

There is a `UIScrollView` in the main `UIView`. I have container `UIView` inside scrollview and its   edges are pinned to scrollview. and this container view has constant `width` and `height` constraints. Because scroll view doesn't work without them.

When I add a lot of sub views inside  the container view vertically  the sub-views exceeds bottom border of container view. It is  not  scrollable cause container has the same predefined height.
How make container view adjustable so it can match sub-views height that will  make it scrollable.

Also consider that I am using `autolayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to do is to update the Height constraint, right?

I would link the Height Constraint of your inside view as an IBOutlet in your ViewController :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)     IBOutlet    NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewHeight;
```

- usual drag and drop to the File's Owner

Then you'll need to update the Constant of your Constraint with a call of that method when you add your subviews inside:

```
- (void)updateContentViewHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    self.contentViewHeight.constant = height;
    [self.yourContentView layoutIfNeeded]; 
}
```

If you can keep track of the Height of the whole stack of subviews, great! you just need to pass it to that method.

If not, it may be a bit more tricky... You may need to remove the Height Constraint, add your subview one below each other (as long as their heights are fixed) without forgetting to "pin" the bottom border of the last Subview to the bottom border of the "inside view".
In other words, the height of the inside view is not fixed but is expanded by the sum of its "height-fixed" content.
This way after:

```
[self.yourContentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

It should have it's final Height in its ".frame"

You should then be able to update the Height Constraint or set the content size of the scrollview, what ever works best for you.